# Visual Basic .Contains() Null Exception

Tags: vb.net, basic

This is my code

```
            Dim words(0) As String
            Dim trie As String
            Dim temp As String
            For i = 1 To 26
                trie = encrypt(a, -i)
                Console.WriteLine(trie)
                For j = 0 To words.Length - 1
                    temp = words(j)
                    If trie.Contains(temp) Then
                        Console.ReadLine()
                    End If
                Next
            Next
```

It should check if trie contains any item in the array words, but it throws a `NULL` exception.

`encrypt(a, -i)` just changes letters in the string

Comment: Lack of detail.. What is `a`?

Comment: What is the exception?

Comment: [`String.Contains`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/dy85x1sa(v=vs.110).aspx) throws an `ArgumentNullException` if the argument passed is a null reference. So you have to check it: `If temp IsNot Nothing AndAlso trie.Contains(temp) Then ...`

Comment: a is a string entered by the user which just has the letters inside of it changed

Answer (score 0):

You have to check if those variables are nulls:

```
Dim words(0) As String = String.Empty
Dim trie As String = String.Empty
Dim temp As String = String.Empty

For i = 1 To 26
  trie = encrypt(a, -i)
  Console.WriteLine(trie)
     For j = 0 To words.Length - 1
         temp = words(j)
         If Not temp Is Nothing AndAlso _ 
            Not trie Is Nothing AndAlso _
                trie.Contains(temp) Then
                Console.ReadLine()
         End If
     Next
 Next
```